# Blackberry: https is VERY slow

Tags: blackberry, https, performance, ksoap2

My app connects to a .NET web service via KSoap2 library. When I'm using HttpConnection everything works great and is very fast. However, when i switch to HttpsConnection the app slows down to a crawl and freezes up the phone. This happens when making soap calls as well as downloading files from my app. I know that https is always going to be slower than http, but it shouldn't take minutes to make a simple call that normally takes a fraction of a second.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Anything i can do about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How much data are you passing in the request/response?  I haven't noticed SSL to be any slower than regular HTTP in our app - but those are relatively small requests (several kilobytes at most).

Comment: Yes, that seems wrong.  BlackBerry has low-level crypto libraries which are quite fast - so that's not the problem here.  Perhaps it has something else to do with the SSL handshake - verifying CAs, etc.  Are you using a well-known CA to sign your certs?  Have you tried connecting via SSL outside of the mobile environment (i.e. browser or other client library) to see if it's also slow?

Comment: We use this same web service for our entire product (including a web client, telephone client, Android, desktop client). We dont have any problems with the others being slow. I added our CA Cert to the phone and marked it as trusted... Could it be that its just the emulator and that an actual device would be faster?

Comment: I didn't know you were on a simulator - yes definitely try on a real device since the networking is quite different between a simulator and real device.

Comment: I have installed the app on a real device and it is even worse. The program completely locks up the device and we have to restart the phone. On the emulator it runs, just really slow. Can anyone help!?!?!